# Increment Invoices number in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `User`, `Job` and `Invoice` models. Every user can create their own jobs and every job have an invoice. Now I need User 1 to have invoice 1, invoice 2 ..... etc   and User 2 to have invoice 1, invoice 2.... etc. So I can't use the id.

Now in `invoices` table I have `invoice_number` (integer) column. How can I increment this invoice_number?

I tried with `before_create :invoice_number` and

```
def invoice_number
  self.invoice_number = Invoice.maximum("invoice_number") + 1
end
```

But I have the same number for all invoices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of your method since it is overriding the attribute name (the way you have it, when you call `invoice.invoice_number`, it is invoking the method and returning `Invoice.maximum("invoice_number") + 1` instead of the attribute stored in the database):

```
before_create :set_invoice_number

def set_invoice_number
  self.invoice_number = self.user.invoices.maximum("invoice_number") + 1
end
```

Comment: Upvoting, but remind him that jobs do get deleted once completed, so need to confirm whether invoices are dependent destroyed with jobs?

Answer (score 6):

While AbM's answer is correct, I think in this case it is important to add uniques validation too:

```
# in your invoice model:
validates :invoice_number, uniqueness: { scope: :user }

before_validation :generate_invoice_number

private
def generate_invoice_number
  self.invoice_number = user.invoices.maximum(:invoice_number).next
end
```

Furthermore, I would add a database constraint to ensure that these numbers are unique per user even in the unlikely event of a race-condition:

```
add_index :invoices, [:user_id, :invoice_number], unique: true
```